# Generating lists of integer numbers with two constraints

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming

I am looking for an effective way to generate all lists of non-negative integer numbers $\{k_0,k_1,k_2\dots\} $ such that
$$\sum_{i\ge0} k_i=K, \quad\sum_{i\ge0} i k_i=N $$
for given $K$ and $N$. The lists should have equal length $N+1$, corresponding to that of the longest set or end with the last non-zero element.

I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variation of @kglr's answer that does what I think your looking for:

```
g[k_, n_] := With[
    {
    p = Catenate @ Map[Permutations] @ PadRight[IntegerPartitions[k, n+1], {Automatic, n+1}]
    },

    Pick[p, p . Range[0, n], n]
]
```

For example:

```
g[2,3]
g[3,5]
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}
>
> {{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>     0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}

Using [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations) makes it rather brute force, so this may be too slow for you. Also, I used a max length of `n+1` instead of `k+1`, changing this is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed what I was looking for.  For some unclear reasons I am unable at the moment to upvote or accept answers. As soon as the problem is solved I will be back. If you find out how to avoid `Permutations` please let me know.

Comment: Upon checking the code I have found that it fails for $n=1$. It seems that replacement `IntegerPartitions[k]`$\rightarrow$`IntegerPartitions[k,n+1]` helps.

Comment: I could not find a description for the option `Automatic` for `PadRight`. Certainly the code does not work without the option. Could you explain how does it work?

Comment: @drer Yes, I think your suggested change is good. As for `PadRight`, `Automatic` means use the existing dimension.

Comment: I have found a way to get rid of `Permutations`. I have posted an answer with the corresponding code. Please take a look at it. I would be very thankful for any suggestions on improving the code, as it looks ugly comparing with those given by experienced *Mathematica* users.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[k_, n_] := Module[{p = PadLeft[Sort /@ IntegerPartitions@k, {Automatic, k + 1}]}, 
  Pick[p, Range[0, k].# & /@ p, n]]
```

**Examples:**

```
 Join @@ Table[{i, #, f[i, #]} & /@ Range[i^2] /. {_, _, {}} -> Sequence[], {i, 2, 6}] // 
 Grid[Prepend[#, {"k", "n", "f[k,n]"}], 
   Dividers -> {All, Thread[{1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 19, 29, -1} -> True]}, 
   Background -> {None, None, {{{2, 3}, {1, -1}} -> LightYellow, 
      {{4, 6}, {1, -1}} -> LightRed, {{7, 11}, {1, -1}} -> LightGreen, 
      {{12, 18}, {1, -1}} -> LightPurple, {{19, -1}, {1, -1}} -> LightBlue}}] &
```

[image]

```
{10, #, f[10, #]} & /@ Range[10^2] /. {_, _, {}} -> Sequence[] // 
  Grid[Prepend[#, {"k", "n", "f[k,n]"}], Dividers -> All] & // TeXForm
```

> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{k} & \text{n} & \text{f[k,n]} \\
> \hline
>  10 & 55 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 64 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 71 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 72 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 76 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 78 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 79 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 80 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 82 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 83 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 84 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 85 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 86 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 87 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 88 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 89 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 90 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 91 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 92 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 93 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 94 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 95 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 96 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 7 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 6 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 97 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 7 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 98 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 99 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
>  10 & 100 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$$

Comment: Probably I was not precise enough. I need not a single reresentative, but the complete list of the requred sets (lists). Besides I have an impresssion that the first element of your lists corresponds to $i=1$, rather than $i=0$.

Comment: @drer, changed the index to start from 0. `f` gives **all**  lists that satisfy the two conditions.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work. The only thing to correct is to allow the value $k_i=0$ as well.

Comment: Besides it seems that your solutions are subject to condition $k_i\le k_{i+1}$.

Comment: @drer, i thought  "_**ordered** non-negative integer numbers_"  meant $k_i \leq k_{i+1}$.

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding. With "ordered" I meant that the index plays role. What I meant was $\{1,2\}\ne\{2,1\}$. I will remove this misleading word.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @drer.

Comment: Thank you once more. I appreciate the work you have done very much and once more sorry if my question was unintentionally unclear.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is intended not to present programming skills (rather opposite) or to give a general recipe for generating lists with several constraints, but instead aims on solving the particular problem. The solution should be much more effective than the brute force approach and uses a bijection between integer partitions and the sets (lists) in question.

I have checked two versions:

```
g1[n_,k_]:=Module[
  {u=Map[Tally] @ IntegerPartitions[n,k],s},
  Table[s=SparseArray[Rule @@ Transpose[u[[i]]],n]//Normal;
  Join[{k-Total[s]},s],{i,Length[u]}]
]

g2[n_,k_]:=Module[
  {u=Map[Tally] @ PadRight[IntegerPartitions[n,k],{Automatic,k}],pos,val},
  Table[{pos,val}=Transpose[u[[i]]];SparseArray[pos+1->val,n+1]//Normal,
  {i,Length[u]}]
]
```

They both appear to give correct result

> g1[5,3]
>
> {{2,0,0,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,1,0},{1,0,1,1,0,0},{0,2,0,1,0,0},{0,1,2,0,0,0}}

and seem to be equally efficient. I would be very thankful for any suggestions on improving the code.

Comment: This looks very good. I think you should make this the accepted answer.